# Rendering Views from Plugin

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I'm trying to modularize my grails app a bit so I'm creating some plugins for some common resources.

If I have layouts, or other views, in my plugin, how would I reference and use them from my main app views? Would I use an attribute in meta to point to the plugin layout? Or the g:applyLayout tag?

ALSO how do I reference CSS, JS and Images which are in my plugin? Using:

```
<script src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'cookie.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

my main app does not find them?

Comment: Plugin component behave as if they're in your local/client app, with the exception of JS and CSS resources (which you have to specify the plugin with the Resources plugin). So if you have the same file in both the plugin and your app, then the app version take precedence. To use the plugin version, just make sure there isn't a local file with the same path/name.

Comment: Hhhmmm...OK I'm trying that now. Follow-up questin: what about plugins within my plugin? I am using the Joda Time plugin, and thought I would put it inside one of MY plugins so that I won't have to declare it in every app...but my Domain Classes won't compile - erroring out on my property definitions: Error Compilation error: startup failed:
C:\grails-projects\portal003\grails-app\domain\portal003\PortalItem.groovy: 22: unable to resolve class DateTime 
 @ line 22, column 2.
    DateTime beginDate

Comment: I removed the joda altogether and cleaned...the above error is gone. I am wondering now how to reference CSS and Images which are in my plugin...I'm going to revise my question above a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bring in CSS/JS/Images from your plugin Use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'nameof.css', plugin: 'nameofplugin')}"   type="text/css">
```

and see also:

http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/resource.html